# Why does the signatureMessageFragment have a fixed size?

Tags: transaction, protocol

A transaction in IOTA consists of **2673 trytes**. The biggest part is the `signatureMessageFragment` (more infos [here](https://iota.readme.io/v1.2.0/docs/the-anatomy-of-a-transaction)) which has a size of **2187 trytes**.

It is used to store the signature of value transactions and it can be used for custom data of 0 value transactions.

If a transaction's `signatureMessageFragment` has leading `9`s, they don't have to be transmitted or stored because the Curl hash function will produce the same result with any amount of leading `9`s.

## Value Transaction

If you want to send IOTAs to another person, you have to create a [Bundle](https://iota.readme.io/v1.2.0/docs/bundles) that consists of 4 or more transactions.

1. recipient output
2. input + first half of signature
3. second half of signature
4. remainder output

With variable size `signatureMessageFragments`, we could put the entire signature into 1 transaction. That would save some *header data* (2673-2187=486 trytes) and even more for multisignature transactions.

**This would reduce the Tangle size significantly, wouldn't it?**

## Data Transaction

If you want to send a *small* amount of data (up to 2187 trytes), you can put it at the end of `signatureMessageFragment` without using up additional space/network because you can ignore the leading `9`s.

But if you want to send a big amount of data (e.g. 16 Kilotrytes (16000 trytes)), you have to make 8 transactions instead of 1. That's a lot of unnecessary header data.

2673-2187=486 trytes
486*8=3888 trytes

`3.9 Kt` *header* for `16Kt` instead of `486 Kt` *header* for `16Kt`

With variable size `signatureMessageFragments`, we could send small amounts of data and big amounts of data in less space.
**This would decrease the Tangle size significantly, wouldn't it?**

## PoW

Of course you'd have to adjust the amount of PoW to the size.
e.g. default POW for up to 2187 Trytes of data, higher difficulty for additional data.
**But it would be possible, wouldn't it?**

---

Even if the Tangle size won't be decreased by a lot because most transaction data would be `<= 2188`.
**It would save at least 486 trytes per value tx, right?**

So:

#### What are the disadvantages of variable size transactions?

Comment: Leading 9s don't need to be transmitted nor stored, with Curl hash function that doesn't change the transaction hash. Take that into account in your math.

Comment: The 9s in the `signatureMessageFragment`? So if the message/signature is `HELLO9CFB999999...` only `HELLO9CFB` has to be stored?

Comment: The field value should be 999...99HELLO9CFB, in this case only HELLO9CFB needs to be transmitted/stored.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

There is no a perfect solution, the both variants (fixed-size and variable-size transactions) have their own pros and cons. These are some pros of fixed-size transactions which make them the best choice for the IoT:

- Smaller codebase for transaction processing (if implemented in software)
- Fewer logic gates for transaction processing (if implemented in hardware)
- Higher security (because of a lower chance for buffer overflow type bugs to happen)
- Reduced resource consumption (because of absence of issues like heap fragmentation)
- Better load balancing (because transaction processing is more predictable)
- Atomic transmission over a physical medium (because packet size can be equal to transaction size + service data)

The list can be continued, it's just what has come to my head now. One could compare fixed-size transactions to fixed-size instructions used in some CPUs.  In the Internet-of-Things there more cases where a fixed size is better than the variable size.