# Maximum how many possible characters to transfer in a message?

Tags: transaction, masked-authenticated-messaging

Since IOTA transaction is free of fee, so it's useful for transferring messages and files with it (compared to, for example, Ethereum that in case of the use of a String, the transaction will be very expensive.)

Now the question is: that how many characters we can transfer in a transaction as a message (maximum)?

Comment: see https://iota.stackexchange.com/questions/700/why-does-the-signaturemessagefragment-have-a-fixed-size

Comment: and https://iota.stackexchange.com/q/168/10

Comment: Also, "[**character**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Character_(computing))" might not be the best unit for measuring storage space because it can mean a lot of things. Use byte or tryte instead?

Comment: @Zauz agree. You can mention equivalent value using bytes or tryte.

Answer (score 3):

When you want to send data via MAM, you have to encode the data in a specific way. The encoded data will be inserted in the signature/message slot of your transaction (0-value txs don't need any signature).
This means that you can put as much data as this protocol allows you to. I'll put here a [youtube video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Nnwn_o_ZBFU) about MAM (the guy doing these tutorials is pretty good, you should check out his other videos too).

Moreover you'll have to convert your strings into trits: every character is converted into two trytes as it is explained [here](https://github.com/iotaledger/kerl/blob/master/IOTA-Kerl-spec.md).

I hope this helped!